# Difference between io.FileIO and open() in binary mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

They produce the same result based on checksum:

```
with open('openb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'asdf')

with io.FileIO('fileio', 'w') as f:
    f.write(b'asdf')
```

Is there any difference between them? When should one method be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the `open()` method will create an `io.BufferedWriter` which inherits from `IOBase` and `FileIO` also inherits from `IOBase`. Though not exactly the same classes, they support basically identical functionality. I suppose you could use FileIO if you know you don't need buffering. There's a lot of info on the [python io docs page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)
The most important sentence there is:

> Raw binary I/O typically provides low-level access to an underlying OS device or API, and does not try to encapsulate it in high-level primitives (this is left to Buffered I/O and Text I/O, described later in this page).

Raw binary I/O relates to io.FileIO and Buffered I/O to the io.BufferedWriter (`open()` method)

Comment: So would it be correct to say that `open()` is optimized for calling `.write()` multiple times, but it is the same as `io.FileIO` if only calling `.write()` once?

Comment: Honestly I haven't thought of that, but I think it is indeed correct to assume that.